# How do you use an specific file from a C# multiselection dialog?

Tags: c#, audio, dialog

I need to use an specific file from the ones you select from a file dialog.

```
OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();

private void pictureBox23_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ofd.Filter = "WAV|*.wav";
    this.ofd.Multiselect = true;
    if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        label23.Text = ofd.SafeFileName;
    }
    else
    {
        label23.Text = "No files selected...";
    }
}
```

What i need to do is select and use the files I pre-define, so if I define an event with 01.wav if the user selects a file named 01.wav, that one will be used like so:

```
using (SoundPlayer player = new SoundPlayer(Beatpadpc.Properties.Resources._01))
{
    player.Play();
}
```

I currently have it adapted as it will play it from the resources, what i need to do is to play the file from the file selecion, but only if the file is named "01".wav

Is there a way for doing it?

Comment: If you are going to check file only by its name, you can iterate throught OpenFileDialog.FileNames array and check if it contains desired name

Answer (score 0):

Well, just filter the ofd property called Filenames.

```
OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
string strAudioFilePath = String.Empty;

private void pictureBox23_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ofd.Filter = "WAV|*.wav";
    this.ofd.Multiselect = true;
    if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        // Here you make a small filter with linq
        label23.Text = strAudioFilePath = ofd.FileNames.FirstOrDefault(x => x.EndsWith("01.wav")); // you change 01.wav to something that make more sense to you
    }
    else
    {
        label23.Text = "No files selected...";
    }
}
```

Then if you want to get rid of your resource file, just give your sound player the path of the file and that's all.

```
SoundPlayer simpleSound = new SoundPlayer(strAudioFilePath);
simpleSound.Play();
```